# How to include a proguard configuration in my Android library (AAR)

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, aar

Android libraries, per the [AAR file spec](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format), includes a 'proguard.txt' file. 
My understanding is that this file declares how the library correctly can be obfuscated and minified. In my case I need to preserve some API-classes.

How can I declare the library's proguard.txt file in the library's build.gradle? And will this file be automatically read when creating an application (APK) that uses my library?

I didn't find this information in Android's Gradle Plugin User Guide.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983248/proguard-ignores-config-file-of-library

Comment: @kevinpelgrims This is about distributing an AAR file with embedded proguard configuration for external library users, I don't expect the answer to be the same, i.e. the library classes wouldn't be minified twice in the multi-module build. The questions are similar though.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In your Gradle file's default configuration closure, specify your Proguard file with `consumerProguardFiles` instead of `proguardFiles`. For example:

```
defaultConfig {
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard.txt'
}
```

Comment: `consumerProguardFiles` should be specified in `defaultConfig` rather than `buildTypes/release` so that it works if the consuming application proguards in both debug and release mode (e.g. to avoid the 65k dex method limit).

Comment: if you are using the gradle experimental plugin(0.7.2) it causes this Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject.

Comment: good example of build.gradle is in this link: https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules/blob/master/rxjava-proguard-rules/build.gradle

Answer (score 7):

**ProGuard artefact**

[[ProGuard workflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285427/4770877)

**Artefact not minified, Consumer solve it**

Library is open-sourced but as a library developer you can provide a ProGuard file which will be take into account by consumer(app) by demand(`minifyEnabled true` in consumer). `consumerProguardFiles` in you library `build.gradle`. It adds `proguard.txt` file(is the same as `.pro`) in an artefact

For example your library is open-source and application developer wants to minify all

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        //consumerProguardFiles '<file_path>'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

**Artefact is minified**

Library is closed-source - you are able to use the next possibility:

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles project(':<project_name>').file('<file_path>')
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

*Please note that:

- `minifyEnabled true` and `proguardFiles project` both should be set.
- If you use single `minifyEnabled true` or `<file_path>` is wrong - `classes.jar` is empty.
- If single `proguardFiles project` - no effect

As for build process on the example of `library - application` - all `.class` files will be merged into single archive with `.dex` extension

Comment: what do you mean "create library" and " distribute your library as archive"? I guess when creating a library it is intended to be used as dependency in other lib or app. In that case shouldnt  it always be minifyEnabled false, since the "library" module here it does not know what function will be referenced by other lib/apps, and hard to determine what to shrink/obfuscate?