# transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' error in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

Hi I am struggling to create release version for my project. I have been try lot of things on Progaurd through SO / Google help but I am still not able to create the release version.

Can somebody help me with this? I always get this issue:

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
> ```

Here is the full detailed error: http://justpaste.it/perror sorry I had to put as a link because it is huge.

Here are dependencies:

```
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
 compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
 compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
 compile project(':pageIndicator')
 compile 'com.github.neopixl:PixlUI:v1.0.6'
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
```

My progaurd file:

```
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-dontwarn com.google.code.**
-dontwarn  org.apache.**
-dontwarn  jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.**
-dontwarn  com.nostra13.universalimageloader.**
-dontwarn  org.acra.** 

#wasabeef recyclerview
-keep class jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#HTTP Legacy
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#Universal Image Loader
-keep class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#Acra
-keep class org.acra.**  { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
#Support libraries
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature

# Keep the annotations
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}


-keep class com.splunk.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class com.splunk.** { *; }
-dontwarn rx.**

-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.**

-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#your package path where your gson models are stored
-keep class com.ylg.others.** { *; }
```

Comment: look like issue with gradle file

Comment: This kind of issue has been known to happen when the SDK version, gradle version and build tools version are incompatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

I've faced the same problem, and haven't been able to solve it.
I've temporarily fixed it by setting `minifyEnabled` to `false`.

Comment: @VedavyasBhat: if we do that it won't Obfuscate my code right?

Comment: @SanjanaNair did u find the solution for this issue?

Comment: @MuthuPandiyan: Nope. Did you get a chance to get it?

Comment: @SanjanaNair Please check out my answer

Answer (score 11):

In your ProGuard file add:

`-ignorewarnings`

***like :***

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in D:\Softwares\Developing\Android\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile


-ignorewarnings
```

**You wouldn't have to specify any package like `com.viewpagerindicator.**` , this will suppress all warnings and the `Gradle Console` will just say like :**

```
......
Warning: there were 4 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

Note: you're ignoring all warnings! 
Ignoring unused library classes...
  Original number of library classes: 4237
  Final number of library classes:    1317
Printing kept classes, fields, and methods...
Shrinking...
......
```

Answer (score 6):

In your ProGuard file add:

`-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**`

If you open up the link you provided and search for 'Warning' about two thirds down you can see the message:

`Warning:com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator: can't find referenced method 'float ceil(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath`

If there are any warnings ProGuard will stop and ask you to fix them first or if your code works you can choose to ignore them with `dontwarn`.

**Update 05/01/2017**

If the warning says `in program class` it is likely that your compiled class files are inconsistent, try removing them all and and rebuilding your project.

If the warning says `in library class` your compiled class files are inconsistent with the libraries. Try recompiling the class files or **upgrading the libraries to consistent versions**.

You can read more [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedprogramclassmember).

Comment: Won't the app crash if it tries to use a method that can't be found?

Comment: ^ I'm desperately trying to figure out why ProGuard picks up these missing references but the regular build doesn't, and how much of a threat they are.

Answer (score 0):

What has helped me was to update all dependencies to last version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the proguard file was totally ignored because the project consisted of several modules. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052696/1942069), the solution was to set the following in the gradle of the module causing the problem:

```
defaultConfig {
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
```

This seems to include the proguard of the module in the application's proguard. Now my `dontwarn` statements are taken in consideration.