# AAR Library Transitive dependencies conflict?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar, transitive-dependency

I was working with an aar released on a local maven repository.
Since I wanted to include the transitive dependencies, I added the `transitive`attribute to my dependencies:

```
compile ('com.mycompany.domain:artifact:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Now, let's say that this project add a dependency on the cardView support library v23:

```
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0"
```

What does it happens to my apk release file if I also add a dependency on the v24 cardView library:

```
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0"
```

Does Gradle is able to manage this double dependecy and take the latest one without generating conflict? Or is it safer to specify depedencies manually without using the `transitive`attribute.

Also, does the `transitive` attribute also import the proGuard rules that the aar could have set?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a few details.

You are using the `@aar` notation.
It means that you want to download only the aar artifact, and no dependencies.
You can check this part of [documentation][1]:
Check the `1.4.1.2. Artifact only notation` section:

> An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which downloads only the artifact file with the specified extension. **Existing module descriptors are ignored**.

Using the `@aar` notation if you want to download the dependencies, you should add `transitive=true`, otherwise you can omit the @aar and it will work without adding the transitive attribute.

About the dependencies.
Gradle will manage the dependencies automatically.
With the default configuration gradle will download the **newest version.**

In any case you can also **exclude** a dependency in your `build.gradle`.

```
 compile('mylibrary:1.0.0') {
     //excluding a particular transitive dependency:
     exclude module: 'xxx' //by artifact name
     exclude group: 'xxx.xxx' //by group
     exclude group: 'xxx.xxxx', module: 'xxxx' //by both name and group

     //disabling all transitive dependencies of this dependency
     transitive = false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer on the Gradle Official Documentation:[Gradle Depedency Management link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Gradle Dependency solver does it automatically.
The two main conflict resolution strategies that Gradle offers are:

**Newest:** The newest version of the dependency is used. This is Gradle's default strategy, and is often an appropriate choice as long as versions are backwards-compatible.

**Fail:** A version conflict results in a build failure. This strategy requires all version conflicts to be resolved explicitly in the build script. See ResolutionStrategy for details on how to explicitly choose a particular version.

Also, cocerning ProGuard, rules should be exported, if declared in the library with following declaration ([see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052696/5292951)):

```
defaultConfig {
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
```