# StackTracing A Proguarded Library and Application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I have a library where I followed this guide to obfuscate my library's code as I am making it a part of a distributable SDK:
[Proguard ignores config file of library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983248/proguard-ignores-config-file-of-library)

ProGuard works as it's supposed to and obfuscates the non-public types and methods. 
Now, say me or another user decides to use this library in their application. They enable ProGuard on as well which causes the application code as well as the library's code to be obfuscated even further. (I noticed that variables or method names that were obfuscated in the library stays the same after the application proguards)

My problem is that I'm not able to map the stacktrace with the aar's mapping.txt in case of a crash. I tried using the application's mapping.txt, which was able to decode the stacktrace 1 level which makes it seem like only the aar's ProGuard is enabled but when I try to use the aar's mapping on this stacktrace, the stacktrace is the same.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any way to get the ensure that stack traces can be properly mapped back to original source code?