# Android Library: Release .aar getting classes.jar empty when using proguard

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-library, android-proguard

I'm trying to generate a library with **minifyEnabled true** but, inside the release .aar, classes.jar is getting empty.

I have checked my **proguard-rules.pro** and it seems to be all right.

I've even created a new module with the default .gradle files and when i set **minifyEnable true** the release version still gets the classes.jar with no class inside.

After all, is it possible to generate an android library obfuscating the code?

EDIT 1: Adding module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile 'fr.bmartel:jspeedtest:1.25'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: What is your proguard rules ?

Comment: Now the proguard rules are all commented.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, I've done this a lot, anyways you should provide some extra information to get an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Ok, check out my first edit, this is my build.gradle. As I said, proguard-rules.pro is all commented and I've already tried to use 

`-keep class com.my.lib. ** {*; }`

Comment: have you solve your problem  ?  my aar still contains no class

Comment: @dx3906 Have you? I'm having this issue on my project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after some time I solved my problem.

I copy/paste a default proguard rules configuration **(library.pro)** to my **proguard-rules.pro**.
You can find this file and more examples in **path-to-your-sdk/tools/proguard/examples**.

For more information, read [this](https://robopress.robotsandpencils.com/how-to-use-proguard-with-your-android-library-c0a2b2b5d3b).

In my **build.gradle** I chagend:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

to:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro' //added this line
     }
 }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For a starting `proguard-rules.pro`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052696/695787