# Jitpack builds successfuly, but jars are empty for every module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, gradle-kotlin-dsl, jitpack

In recent release of our library we decided to add some kotlin-dsl features to our build, though for now we've added buildSrc build.gradle.kts and Dependencies.kts file containing libraries versions for easier use across all modules. 
**The problem is that this version builds successfuly on jitpack, but downloaded jars are empty. How do I fix this?** Also all the resource files are present. The build log file also differs much from previous ones.

[Problematic build log file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/netigenkluzowicz/api_android/2.4.1/build.log)

[Working build log file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/netigenkluzowicz/api_android/2.4.0-rc01/build.log)

A link to library on jitpack: https://jitpack.io/#netigenkluzowicz/api_android

[Github link](https://github.com/netigenkluzowicz/api_android) 
branch to reproduce these build problems is feature/kotlin, we're working to fix it on fix/jitpack-build branch

**To Reproduce**

Add this dependency to an Android project, sync and check classes.jars
    implementation 'com.github.netigenkluzowicz:api_android:2.4.1'

What we did before this problem started to occur:
Added buildSrc directory with build.gradle.kts and Dependencies.kts.

We also extracted android { } block from our modules build.gradle files, it is now applied from android.gradle file.

I've already went through jitpack issues on github, all I found so far are build errors with kotlin-dsl from late 2018. Was following [this guide](https://proandroiddev.com/migrate-to-gradle-kotlin-dsl-in-4-steps-f3e3b27e1f4d) to make a use of kotlin-dsl, though due to having issues with android { } block I didn't migrate all of our gradle files.

Comment: I had the same problem
[this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652924/android-library-release-aar-getting-classes-jar-empty-when-using-proguard)