# Failed to find byte code for Volley when using it in an Android library AAR

Tags: android, android-volley, proguard, android-proguard

I'm using Volley in a library project that I've built into a AAR file.

I add the AAR file into the main project. When building the main project, I get the following error:

`Failed to find byte code for com/android/volley/Response$Listener`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the Proguard config, however I get the error even if I build a debug variant when creating the AAR.

This is my Proguard file for the library project:

```
# Volley
-dontwarn com.android.volley.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.error.**
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Response$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Request$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$* { *; }
-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.*
```

Any tips on what might be causing this?

**Update**: I've tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052696/1020311 regarding the `consumerProguardFiles` Proguard file, but I still get the same error when building the main project.

I also tried the default `proguard-library.pro` file along with my Volley lines:

```
#
# This ProGuard configuration file illustrates how to process a program
# library, such that it remains usable as a library.
# Usage:
#     java -jar proguard.jar @library.pro
#

# Specify the input jars, output jars, and library jars.
# In this case, the input jar is the program library that we want to process.

# -injars  in.jar
# -outjars out.jar

# -libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar

# Save the obfuscation mapping to a file, so we can de-obfuscate any stack
# traces later on. Keep a fixed source file attribute and all line number
# tables to get line numbers in the stack traces.
# You can comment this out if you're not interested in stack traces.

#-printmapping out.map
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod

# Preserve all annotations.

-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Preserve all public classes, and their public and protected fields and
# methods.

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

# Preserve all .class method names.

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration
# classes.

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
# You can comment this out if your library doesn't use serialization.
# If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward
# compatible, please refer to the manual.

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Your library may contain more items that need to be preserved;
# typically classes that are dynamically created using Class.forName:

# -keep public class mypackage.MyClass
# -keep public interface mypackage.MyInterface
# -keep public class * implements mypackage.MyInterface

# Volley
-dontwarn com.android.volley.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.error.**
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Response$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Request$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$* { *; }
-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.*
```

Additionally I've tried commenting out the Proguard lines in `buildTypes`, since the module will be open source and I'm not needing obfuscation, but still no luck.

This is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-library.pro'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-library.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

Could I be making the AAR file wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: @FcoP. Added, thanks

Comment: That's the proguard file, I meant the build.gradle file

Comment: @FcoP. sorry, misread your comment. There it is. Thanks

Comment: weird, I made a test project using your files and it still compiles, I set both release and debug to use proguard. can you check? https://github.com/fcopardo/stackOverflowQuestion1

Answer (score 2):

> **Failed to find byte code** for **`com/android/volley/Response$Listener`**

The thing that I concerned about, was this:

```
consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-library.pro'
```

You used this line of code in both `release` and `defaultConfig` block and I believe this causes the issue.

[Check the comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052696/4409113)

> consumerProguardFiles **should be specified in defaultConfig** *rather than
>   buildTypes/release* so that it works if the consuming application
>   proguards in both debug and release mode (e.g. to avoid the 65k dex
>   method limit)

**P.S:** Progaurd rules doesn't seem to be the issue. At least, you can try updating Appcompat then testing the project as well as I created a test project and it worked with your current codes.

Comment: `-keep` tells proguard **not** to obfuscate the matched specification. https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#application

Answer (score 2):

better comment out `-dontwarn` and add `-verbose` (on top), while testing the rules.

... the required rule might either be:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.android.volley.** { *; }
```

or with two `**` (the same applies to all the other entries, with a single `*`):

```
-keep class com.android.volley.Response$** { *; }
```

it could be even explicitly spelled-out, alike:

```
-keep class com.android.volley.Response$Listener { *; }
```

about like this:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Response$** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Request$** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$** { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$** { *; }
#-dontwarn com.android.volley.error.**
#-dontwarn com.android.volley.**

# not sure if this one is required
#-keep interface com.android.volley.** { *; }

-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**
#-dontwarn org.apache.**
```